# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source instead of ViewExpiredException with Mojarra 2.1.11

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jboss, mojarra

I am using Mojarra 2.1.11 and JBoss AS 6.1.0. I have the same issue as brought up in [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792437/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-null-source) but the answer does not work for me.

The xhtml on the page is syntactically proper (I've tried this with many pages) so I don't think that is the problem. Error text:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
at java.util.EventObject.<init>(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_31]
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:71) [:2.1.11]
at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:73) [:2.1.11]
at javax.faces.event.PostRestoreStateEvent.<init>(PostRestoreStateEvent.java:73) [:2.1.11]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:271) [:2.1.11]
...
```

In web.xml I've set my session timeout to 1 minute, and any page I test produces the above error after that one minute. If I understand correctly, this should instead be producing a ViewExpiredException. If anyone has any idea of something else I can try, I would appreciate it.

Thanks,
Clé

:edit 7/28/2012 - stack trace for project:

```
16:55:01,663 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/TestProject
16:55:01,711 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
16:55:01,789 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] Initializing Mojarra 2.1.11 ( 20120711-1632) for context '/TestProject'
16:55:03,692 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080
16:55:03,692 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8009
16:55:03,692 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8443
16:55:03,692 INFO  [org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer] JBossAS [6.1.0.Final "Neo"] Started in 30s:523ms
16:56:59,846 WARN  [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters] Parameters: Invalid chunk ignored.
16:56:59,846 WARN  [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters] Parameters: Invalid chunk ignored.

16:57:01,642 WARN  [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters] Parameters: Invalid chunk ignored.
16:57:01,642 WARN  [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters] Parameters: Invalid chunk ignored.
16:57:01,642 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver] Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
16:57:03,219 WARN  [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters] Parameters: Invalid chunk ignored.
16:57:03,219 WARN  [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters] Parameters: Invalid chunk ignored.
16:59:37,112 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/TestProject].[Faces Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
at java.util.EventObject.<init>(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_31]
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:71) [:2.1.11]
at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:73) [:2.1.11]
at javax.faces.event.PostRestoreStateEvent.<init>(PostRestoreStateEvent.java:73) [:2.1.11]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:271) [:2.1.11]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:257) [:2.1.11]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [:2.1.11]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [:2.1.11]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [:2.1.11]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [:2.1.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:67) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_31]
```

If the full stack trace from when the server starts until the error happens would be useful, please let me know.

Comment: The complete stacktrace would have been helpful.

Comment: Looking in [JBoss AS 6.1.0 component list](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossas/tags/6.1.0.Final/component-matrix/pom.xml), I see Mojarra 2.0.3-b5 as `version.javax.faces`. Are you sure your app is REALLY using mojarra version 2.1.11?

Comment: You can verify which JSF implementation your app is really using, checking the contents of: `FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` while running on JBoss

Comment: @eljunior: version info and line numbers in stacktrace so far confirms 2.1.11.

Comment: @BalusC oh, you're right, my bad, thank you! My eyes skipped reading that without thinking...

Comment: I've updated the original question to add in the full stack trace. Hopefully that helps, I am at a loss.

Comment: I reproduced the same issue with exactly the same stacktrace and steps. http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2610 has the same symptoms, but I reproduced the issue without SWF. Anyways, upgrading to 2.1.6 resolves the issue (you still see a warning in log, which may indicate the issue is still presented in JSF).