# JSF form with URL action?

Tags: forms, url, jsf-2, action

Is there any way to call a URL action within a `<h:commandButton>`, or for that matter a `<h:form>`? I'm trying to bypass my email's login page from my own website, so I'm using JSF beans to hold my login info in `<h:inputSecret>` tags so that I can simply click "Go to Email" and because I'm logged in to my own website, I could go straight to my inbox w/o logging in again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use plain HTML `<form>` instead of JSF `<h:form>`.

```
<form action="http://example.com/mail" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="#{bean.username}" />
    <input type="password" name="password" value="#{bean.password}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Email" />
</form>
```

Comment: I always get `javax.servlet.ServletException: null source
` when I try to insert a plain html `<form>` into a JSF page

Comment: or when I try to set the action of a `<h:commandButton>` to a URL

Comment: The `null source` exception is recognizeable as a bug in older Mojarra versions which can under the covers actually be caused by a simple XML syntax error. E.g. a missing closing tag or missing quotes. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792437/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-null-source/4793340#4793340 As to the incorrect way of using the `action` attribute of the `<h:commandButton>`, I have nowhere told/answered that you can do that, so I'm not sure why you're trying to do that.

Comment: just saying what I had tried. as always, you're the best. Thanks!