# JSF2/RICHFACES4 How to validate javax.faces.ViewState value?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

Is there any kind of API for validating if the javax.faces.ViewState value posted from client is a valid value or not? It can be standard JSF2 or Richfaces4 API.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? If it's invalid, JSF will throw `ViewExpiredException` during restore view. It would make completely sense to just catch it.

Comment: Unfort my jsf-api is buggy, does not throw ViewExpiredException. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792437/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-null-source. I can not upgrade my jsf-api.

Comment: I'd work on the problem of "I can not upgrade".